# Integer argument with a leading zero is parsed as octal by flag.IntVar or flag.Int

Tags: go

I wrote this code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "flag"

func main() {
    
    var i int
    
    flag.IntVar(&i, "i", 0, "help")
    flag.Parse()

    if i < 9 {
        fmt.Println("i < 9")
    }

    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

When I run this command:

```
./a -i 10
10
```

the output is correct.

But why, if I run it with `010`, does Golang parse `010` as a octal (`010` == `8`)?

```
./a -i 010
i < 9
8
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: Octal syntax using a preceding 0 is pretty standard in a lot of languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oof, that’s a terrible gotcha.

> Is this a bug?

It was [added intentionally](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/37b178739279d2ab17b836de64375401abdda8ae) in 2011, before Go 1.0.0.

> flag: allow hexadecimal and octal input for integer flags.

You can find the full behavior in the documentation for [`strconv.ParseInt`](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#ParseInt), not that its use in `flag` is documented.